# How to get multiple categories product on particular page in Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using "Classic Next Light " Theme in bigcommerce . I want to display multiple categories product on particular page.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? or provide an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is far too brief and broad to be answerable. Please show what you mean exactly, in the question itself, and also add what things you have tried in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply T.J .. Its solved now. Sory for late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the jQuery to load multiple categories product on one page.
create a two div on landing page.

```
<div id="Cat1"></div>
<div id="Cat1"></div>
```

then add this code into landing page after that div:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Cat1").load("http://medical-coding-net.mybigcommerce.com/categories/cat1.html .ProductList ");
});
$("#Cat2").load("http://medical-coding-net.mybigcommerce.com/categories/cat2.html .ProductList ");
});
</script>
```